# Android - duplicate "open with" system dialog instance after orientation change

Tags: android, android-intent, orientation-changes

I have simple activity with one button. When button is clicked, I'm firing intent to pick image from gallery. Something strange is going on when I fire intent and then rotate the screen. Here are the steps:

1. Click button. "Open with" system dialog appears.
2. Rotate screen. Activity gets recreated, dialog is still shown. Note - I don't call startActivityForResult(Intent, int) again on my activity recreate.
3. Tap back button. "Open with" dialog disappear, but there is another one beneath it.

So it seems even though I don't call startActivityForResult(Intent, int), new instance of dialog gets created every orientation change, and old instance don't getting destroyed.

Does anyone facing this issue? How to get rid of these duplicate dialogs?

**Update 1:**
So, here is some sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private boolean mIsStarted = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            mIsStarted = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("key");
        }

        if (!mIsStarted)
        {
            mIsStarted = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MimeType.IMAGE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean("key", mIsStarted);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        mIsStarted = false;
    }
}
```

I also tried to set `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|mcc|mnc"` and still every time I rotate the screen, new copy of dialog (actually this is not a dialog, this is [ResolverActivity](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/com/android/internal/app/ResolverActivity.java)) being showed on top of previous one. Is this some Android bug or it's just me doing something wrong?

**Update 2:** so I tried another approach - call [finishActivity(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity(int)) inside my `Activity.onStop()`. Result is pretty strange - now I've got only 2 copies of [ChooserActivity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com$java$ext@com.google.android$android@1.5_r4@com$android$internal$app$ChooserActivity.java). After second copy is created, it starts rotating fine.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.make_photo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MimeType.IMAGE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStop");

        super.onStop();

        finishActivity(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("onActivityResult[requestCode:%d, resultCode:%d, data:%s]",
                requestCode, resultCode, data != null ? data.toString() : "NULL"));
    }
}
```

Still wonder why second copy is being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out this was silly mistake in my base `Activity` class. I end up with deriving all my `Activities` which works with intents from this base `IntentProcessingActivity` class.

```
/**
 * Base activity for all activities which process intents. This activity saves processing state
 * during recreation, so derived activities can get rid of this. This is useful for not showing
 * "Open with" dialogs multiple times.
 * <p />
 * Derived activities can check if some intent is currently processing with {@link
 * #isProcessingIntent()} function.
 * <p />
 * Created by Maksimov Stanislav (s.maks04@gmail.com) on 25.01.16
 */
public class IntentProcessingActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String KEY_IS_PROCESSING_INTENT = "IsProcessingIntent";

    private boolean mIsProcessingIntent;

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            mIsProcessingIntent = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_PROCESSING_INTENT, false);
        }
    }

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_PROCESSING_INTENT, mIsProcessingIntent);
    }

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)
    {
        mIsProcessingIntent = true;
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, options);
    }

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
    {
        mIsProcessingIntent = true;
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        mIsProcessingIntent = false;
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    protected final boolean isProcessingIntent()
    {
        return mIsProcessingIntent;
    }
}
```

On child `Activities` I just check

```
if (!isProcessingIntent())
{
    startActivityForResult(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the activity declatation in your `androidmanifest.xml`

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This will prevent the activity from getting recreated and resolve the issue of duplicate dialog.

Comment: But what if I actually need to support different orientations?

Comment: ignore previous comment, this will continue to support orientation change- it will just not recreate activity.

Comment: Even if I have different layouts for different orientations?

Comment: no in that case you'll have to go about setting a flag to check if the orientation has changed and not put the thing in actual answer.